# Matrices Multiplication With Data in Polar Form?

Tags: matlab, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

I am taking a power engineering class and I have to multiply two matrices (3x3) together which have values in polar form. I have access to Matlab and Mathematica. I googled it but the results weren't specific at all. I'd appreciate any tangible feedback!

Answer (score 1):

### In MATLAB:

### Converting Polar Form to Real and Imaginary Components

With the brief details given, I would first convert all the polar form terms into their corresponding real and imaginary components this way they can be stored in an array. In this test example, I created a few arbitrary data sets named `Magnitudes_1`, `Angles_1`, `Magnitudes_2` and `Angles_2`
to represent the polar form arguments in the two matrices. Applying the `sind()` and `cosd()` relationships element-wise across the matrices allows us to retrieve the corresponding real and imaginary components. We can then combine these real and imaginary components into single arrays using the `complex()` function. After this, the arrays can be multiplied either by matrix-multiplication or element-wise, but of course, depending on your use case these may or. may not pertain to your task at hand. Converting back to magnitude-angle arrays (polar-form) can be done by using `tand()` on the imaginary/real components and Pythagorean theorem or the `abs()` function to obtain the magnitude.

[image: Output Results of Multiplication of Matrices]

### Playground Script:

```
clear;
clc;

%Matrix 1%
%Random test magnitudes and angles%
Magnitudes_1 = [1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1]; 
Angles_1 = [0 0 0; 0 120 240; 0 240 120];

%Converting into real and imaginary components%
Real_Components_1 = Magnitudes_1.*cosd(Angles_1);
Imaginary_Components_1 = Magnitudes_1.*sind(Angles_1);


%Combining the components into a complex array%
Complex_Array_1 = complex(Real_Components_1,Imaginary_Components_1);

%Matrix 2%
%Random test magnitudes and angles%
Magnitudes_2 = [20 40 32; 100 70 290; 50 30 10];
Angles_2 = [2 50 93; 32 65 295; 315 300 290];

%Converting into real and imaginary components%
Real_Components_2 = Magnitudes_2.*cosd(Angles_2);
Imaginary_Components_2 = Magnitudes_2.*sind(Angles_2);

%Combining the components into a complex array%
Complex_Array_2 = complex(Real_Components_2,Imaginary_Components_2);


%MULTIPLYING THE ARRAYS%
%Matrix multiplication%
Result_1 = Complex_Array_1*Complex_Array_2;

%Element-wise multiplication%
Result_2 = Complex_Array_1.*Complex_Array_2;
```

---

### Extension: Conversion Back to Polar Form:

To convert back to polar form we can use `abs()` to find the magnitude of the complex terms (real and imaginary i terms). The `angle()` function can then be used to find the angles in radians. To convert back to degrees the conversion factor (360 degrees/2π) can be used.

```
Result_Magnitude_1 = abs(Result_1);
Result_Angle_1 = angle(Result_1);
Result_Angle_1 = Result_Angle_1*(360/2*pi);

Result_Magnitude_2 = abs(Result_2);
Result_Angle_2 = angle(Result_2);
Result_Angle_2 = Result_Angle_2*(360/2*pi);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it. However, Complex_Array line doesn't work. Try for these values:
Magnitudes_1 = [1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1];
Angles_1 = [0 0 0; 0 120 240; 0 240 120];

Comment: It ran it with the new matrices and it somehow still works. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks again for helping out! For instance, cos(120 degrees) is -.5. Here is what I am getting for column 2: 
                          1 +                     0i
          0.814180970526562 +     0.580611184212314i
          0.325781305535148 +     0.945445154921117i

Comment: My bad try changing `sin()` and `cos` to `sind()` and `cosd()` to signiy we're working with degrees.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! It works. So the last step. How do I convert these three complex values back to polar form?                                                                                  
       2.6955 -     4.2568i
       270.6 +     31.257i
       6.7058 -         27i

Comment: NIce, you can use `abs()` of the array to get the magnitudes. Then use `angle()` to get the corresponding angles in radians. Then the radians need to be converted back to degrees.